# Routing in Express, route to the '/' or '/login'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to route this URL that match with '/' or '/login'.
I have this and doesn't work...

```
app.use('/?:login', require('./routes/loginRouter'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below route path which will match paths `/` or `/logic`

```js
app.use('/.{0}(login)?.{0}', require('./routes/loginRouter'));
```

Reference: [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-579fgh?file=index.js) on StackBlitz

Comment: No, it gives me an error... I think is because i use app.use() and not app.get(), but i need to use app.use()

Comment: @UrielEspada Do you have `router.get` or `router.post` in login router?

Comment: @UrielEspada checkout the updated answer based on partial routes

Comment: the thing is that i want to access to the URL puting `http://myweb.com` or `http://myweb.com/login`

Comment: @UrielEspada please check if this route path meets your requirement `/.{0}(login)?.{0}`

Comment: You did it !!! Thanks